# How to import multiple modules using webpackChunkName

Tags: webpack

To chunking the imports in webpack, we do something like this

```
const Component = () =>
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "mycomp" */ "node_modules/myComponent");
```

What if myComponent is exporting multiple componets like

```
export {myComponent, Component1, Component2}
```

How to import such multiple components via webpackChunkName?